# PostgreSQL array error

Tags: arrays, postgresql, triggers

I am new at `PostgreSQL` , I create 2 table

```
CREATE TABLE HOUR(
id integer,
hour timestamp ) ;

CREATE TABLE ACTIVITY_TIME(
id integer,
day_hours varchar[][] ) ;
```

`day_hours` column is a `array` of combinations number of week, and id of `HOUR` table .Value of that column look like `{{1,5},{2,5},{2,6}}`. I tried creat a trigger, when i delete a `hour` from `HOURS` table , in `ACTIVITY_TIME` I have to remove in day_hours where that hour is exist . For example, if I delete `id=6` from `HOUR` the result of `day_hours` will be `{{1,5},{2,5}}` , or if `day_hours` `{{3,2},{3,4},{4,2}}` and if I delete `id=2` from `HOUR` the result of `day_hours` will be `{{3,4}}`. I know how write trigger, but I can't write the `procedure` which is execute array

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT
        "unnest" (
            "DAY_HOURS" [ 1 : array_length("DAY_HOURS",1)][ 1 : 1 ]:: INT []
        ) AS days,
        "unnest" (
            "DAY_HOURS" [ 1 : array_length("DAY_HOURS",1)][ 2 : 2 ]:: INT []
        ) AS hours
    FROM
        "ACTIVITY_TIME"
    WHERE
        "ID" = 3
) 

SELECT ARRAY(SELECT ARRAY[ s.days,s.hours] FROM
    summary s WHERE s.hours!= 2 )
```

This give `error :could not find array type for data type integer[]` error,

Comment: I really strongly recommend *not* trying to work with things like multidimensional arrays if you're new to PostgreSQL.

Comment: I know, at the beginning google it. But it is supporting project, i have to use it for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the function `array()` (I mean the function `array()` and not the constructor `ARRAY[]`) does not accept an array as argument. This query:

```
SELECT array(select array[1,2]);
```

give you the error:

```
ERROR:  could not find array type for data type integer[]
```

The function `array()` accept instead a set as argument. Use the function `unnest` to convert a array in a set:

```
SELECT array(select unnest(array[1,2]));

-- Result:
--   array 
--  -------
--   {1,2}
```

However this would unnest all elements of your bidimensional array in one dimensional array. As workaroud can you first cast the arrays to text, build a array of texts, cast again in text, remove the quotes and finally cast the text result in a bidimensional array:
You query would look like so:

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT
        unnest (
            DAY_HOURS [ 1 : array_length(DAY_HOURS,1)][ 1 : 1 ]:: INT []
        ) AS days,
        unnest (
            DAY_HOURS [ 1 : array_length(DAY_HOURS,1)][ 2 : 2 ]:: INT []
        ) AS hours
    FROM
        ACTIVITY_TIME
    WHERE
        ID = 3
) 
select replace(array(SELECT  ARRAY[ s.days,s.hours]::text FROM  -- <<< change this line
    summary s WHERE s.hours!= 2 )::text, '"','')::int[][] AS array; -- <<< change this line
```

This returns:

```
        array        
---------------------
 {{1,5},{2,5},{2,6}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: it is good, but result is one dimensional array, i need two dimensional array.